# When I try to run dotnet react project, it raises "Couldn't start the SPA development server with command 'npm start' "

Tags: reactjs, .net-core

I created a dotnetReact application by using vsCode with "dotnet new react".
The project created successfully.
But when I try to run the project with "dotnet run" it raises this error. Please refer to the following screenshot.

[image: The error raised when I tried to run the app.]

Please help on this issue.